# What do Negative Atomic Orbital Contributions in a Mulliken Population Analysis mean?

Tags: density-functional-theory, computational-chemistry, molecular-modeling, ab-initio-calculations, population-analysis

I am performing a Mulliken population analysis (MPA) for a molecular system of interest (calculated with B3LYP/Def2-TZVP). I am analyzing the LCAO-MO coefficients/contributions associated with each "atomic orbital" towards a particular set of Kohn-Sham canonical orbitals. I have encountered a semi-expected problem being the negative orbital contributions.

For example, consider this simple fictional system with the LCAO-MO of the following simple system with three atomic orbital functions:

$$\psi_{i}=\sum_{\mu=1}^{3}c_{i\mu}\phi_{\mu}$$
$$\psi_{1}=\underset{90\%}{c_{11}\phi_{1}}+\underset{12\%}{c_{12}\phi_{2}}+\underset{-2\%}{c_{13}\phi_{3}}$$
$$\psi_{2}=\underset{-2\%}{c_{21}\phi_{1}}+\underset{90\%}{c_{22}\phi_{2}}-\underset{12\%}{c_{23}\phi_{3}}$$
$$\psi_{3}=\underset{12\%}{c_{31}\phi_{1}}-\underset{-2\%}{c_{32}\phi_{2}}-\underset{90\%}{c_{33}\phi_{3}}$$

The numbers underneath the linear combination terms represents the percentage orbital character as calculated with the MPA scheme. The sums of the columns/rows of the orbital contributions all equal one, which signifies that the atomic orbitals are normalized and have equal contribution summed over the set of molecular orbitals.

I have read in the software manual of the program that the MPA method can result in negative orbital populations atomic orbitals with strong bonding or antibonding overlap populations as a result of equal partitioning of electron density, however, I have trouble analyzing the physical meaning of the negative orbital contributions.

Does this mean my data is completely unreliable, or does it mean that it falls within the error associated with the MPA method?

This is my first attempt at LCAO-MO analysis, and my knowledge on this subject is self-taught and limited. It is very possible I could be making a conceptual error. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: I'll quote the late, great [Vic Saunders](https://www.imperial.ac.uk/computational-materials-science/news/) when I asked him this very question: "It means you have a crap basis set"

Comment: There is nothing physical about Mulliken populations...

Comment: @IanBush on the contrary, Mulliken works best in a minimal basis. It is rather when going to large basis sets that one gets into problems. Mulliken charges have no basis set limit, since one can span the complete basis set in an arbitrary number of ways.

Comment: @SusiLehtola, I might still have a conceptual error: I understand that Mulliken populations don’t correspond to anything in physical reality; however, since the “atomic orbital” functions are a mathematical tool used to approximate the many-electron wave function, wouldn’t -2% of a mathematical function be an error in the pop analysis? Any clarification is appreciated!

Comment: Atomic gross populations aren't observables. Bond populations even less so.

Comment: Off-diagonal elements are not positive definite, so negative values make complete sense. You could interpret them as destructive interference.